# Can I connect 5v 1 amp usb mobile charger to power Node MCU?

Tags: nodemcu

I am planning to power Node MCU from cable power. Can I connect mobile charger to the micro USB port? Or is it better to connect to Vin in NodeMCU?

Comment: Are you trying to ask if you can connect a power supply with a higher current rating than needed? If so, this question has been answered approximately 129,134,987 times on this site and an answer shouldn't be difficult to locate. Unless you were trying to ask something else?

Comment: @MCG Please read the question! The question is not about current! but if the preferred way to feed the power to a NodeMCU, Micro USB or Win pin.

Comment: @MatsK usually, the reason people ask if they can use a different supply to power their device (specifying current as in the title), it is to ask about current rating. I did read the question. There was no specifying *why* it was being asked, so I thought it was likely to be because of the current rating as it was mentioned in the title. Looks like winny thought the same too, hence marking a duplicate. That is why I asked OP what they meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this circuit, and [simple search on google...](http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/powering-the-esp-12e-nodemcu-development-board/)

[image: circuit]

Vin is connected to VDD5V which is connected with a schottcky diode to USB5V.

This means you can power by either Vin or by USB, it won't make any difference, except for the voltage drop across D1.